# Calibrating the accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, calibration

I am working on an application which utilizes accelerometer data to detect fall and no movement ,
when i set the phone on a flat surface and sampled 2000 accelerometer readings in the X and Y and Z directions (parallel to the table,  gravity acting in Z direction). I then averaged these readings and used this value to calibrate the phone (subtracting this value from each subsequent reading).
i got these readings

```
z = 8.97 
y = 0.10
x = 0.3
```

but when i change the orientation(for example : screen facing the ground)
i got these readings

```
z = -10.228 
y = -0.181
x = -0.009
```

and same for other angles.

so my question is how can i calibrate the accelerometer to fit all possible orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, you cannot calibrate cheap accelerometer.

Good news, you don't need the calibration for the `fall` and `no movement` detection.

The `fall` is when the sum of all accelerations is below 5 (for example), and the `no movement` is when all accelerations stay stable for a short while.